# Riemann-integrability of two functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f, g:[0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ be functions defined as$$
f(t) =\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin t}{t},& t \neq 0 \\0,& t= 0 \end{cases}, \quad g(t) =\begin{cases}\dfrac {\sin t}{t^2},& t \neq 0 \\0,& t= 0 \end{cases},
$$
then

a. both $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$.

b. $f$ is Riemann-integrable but $g$ is not Riemann-integrable on $[0, 1]$.

c. $g$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0, 1]$ but $f$ is not Riemann-integrable on $[0, 1]$.

d. both $f$ and $g$ are not Riemann-integrable on $[0, 1]$.

my attempts :  i thinks  option b)  will coorect  because   $f(t)$ is continious  at $0$  but $g(t)$  is not continious .

Any hints/solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean $f$ is continuous near $0$?

Comment: yes@Holo.....,,,

Comment: yes,  it is correct, but $f$ is not continuous. It is true because there is only finite (1) points of discontinuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is not continuous at $0$ because $$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \downarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 .$$

Although, $f$ is Riemann integrable because it contains only $1$ point of discontinuity of the first kind (by Lebesgue's integrability criteria).

Also, if a function $h$ is Riemann integrable on the interval $[a,b]$, then it is bounded on $[a,b]$. Since $$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \downarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} = \infty,$$ $g$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: thanks a lots @C_M

Comment: @1TOPLOGY You're welcome!